# Use the event onselect in JSP to modifiy another controller

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

I have 2 comboBox in JSP and I want to add the item selected in "list" to "list2". I don't know how to do that in the function "change".

```
<select name="list" onselect="change(this)">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
</select>

<select name="list2">
</select>

<%! public void change(String val) {

} %>
```

Comment: You can't do it with a Java scriptlet, which won't be present in the generated HTML.

Comment: Your onchange function must be javascript since all UI stuff runs on the client. If you need to do anything serverside, it will need to use an AJAX request.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do it by using `jQuery`.

Here is an example:

[Display results from select dropdown then clone and add another select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18972846/display-results-from-select-dropdown-then-clone-and-add-another-select)

Answer (score 0):

As Shreyos has said, this is easy to achieve in JQuery.

For example, a simple JQuery implementation that adds the selected option from list1 to list2 (if it doesn't already exist) may look like this:

```
$(function() {
    var $list1 = $('select[name=list]');
    var $list2 = $('select[name=list2]');

    $list1.change(function() {
        var optionSelector = 'option[value=' + $(this).val() + ']';
        if ($list2.find(optionSelector).length == 0) {
            $selectedOption = $(this).find(optionSelector);
            $list2.append($selectedOption.clone());
        }
    });
});
```

See it running on JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/8g8Q2/)